# Checking function with spaces in it in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this query

```
"SELECT * FROM items WHERE itemname LIKE '%$name%'"
```

If `$name="alex"`, then the query returns the correct information. But if  `$name="alex  "` with trailing whitespace, then no results are returned.

If `$name="alex dude"`, then this is valid, but `$name="alex dude "` is not. I only want to remove whitespace at the end of the string.

I have written a function to clear out spaces at the end of name. This is the function.

```
function checkname($dataname)
{
    $func_name ="";
    $checker = substr($dataname, -1);
    if($checker == " ")
    {
        $func_name = substr_replace($dataname, "", -1)
        function checkname($dataname);
    }
    else
    {
        $dataname = $func_name;
    }
    return $dataname;
}
```

This gives me a PHP Parse error:

> syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION) in C:\inetpub\vhosts\httpdocs\compare.php on line 176`.

I don't understand why recursively calling a function is giving me an error.

Can you guys help out with this? Is there a better solution or better SQL query than I am using?

Comment: PHP has a built in function for trimming trailing whitespaces - check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: Rob if I enter $name="alex dude" then this is a valid name but $name="alex dude    " this is not valid

Comment: I don't need to remove all the whitespaces

Comment: `trim()` only removes the **trailing** whitespaces, not the ones that are non trailing.

Comment: @Rob `trim` also removes **leading** whitespace.

Comment: I'm surprised no one has mentioned this so far, but regardless of how you trim the whitespace, you should be binding this variable to a prepared statement rather than interpolating it into the SQL string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do direcly in sql

```
"SELECT * FROM items WHERE itemname LIKE concat('%', trim('$name'), '%')"
```

or rtrim

```
"SELECT * FROM items WHERE itemname LIKE concat('%', rtrim('$name'), '%')"
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons you'll get errors. The first reason, and the reason you're seeing the message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'function'

is that you're missing a semicolon after `$func_name = substr_replace($dataname, "", -1)`.

`function` is unexpected because you haven't terminated the previous line.

If you fix that, you'll still get an error, because you're using `function checkname($dataname);` to do the recursive call, when it should be `return checkname($dataname);` If you use it the way you have it, you'll get a `cannot redeclare function` error.

If you want it to work recursively, it can be simplified to

```
function checkname($dataname) {
    if (substr($dataname, -1) == " ") {
        return checkname(substr_replace($dataname, "", -1));
    }
    return $dataname;
}
```

But as others have said, this does basically the same thing as `trim()` or `rtrim()`.

Comment: Actually, you don't have to call the function it self :)

Comment: @Chay22 Please explain what you mean?

Comment: `return substr_replace($dataname, "", -1);` is enough rather call the function twice.

Comment: @Chay22 That would only remove one extra space. The recursive call is used to remove multiple spaces. Kind of pointless considering there's a built-in function that does it, but since OP was trying to use recursion, I wanted to show them a way that it would work.

Comment: Oh I see, I saw only `$name="alex dude "` as what OP needed to trim out which is a space.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I was just trying to give some explanation for his statement: _"I don't understand why recursively calling function giving me error. "_

Answer (score 0):

You can use `trim`, it's PHP native function stripping whitespace  from the beginning and end of a string.

```
$trimmed = trim(' my string ');
echo $trimmed; // 'my string'
```

You can find more informations regarding it in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).

By default, it will remove ordinary space, tab, new line, carriage return, NUL-byte and vertical tabs.

You can also control which characters are removed at the start and end of the string by using a second parameter to the `trim` function as specified in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE itemname LIKE '%". trim($dataname) ."%'"
```

trim($string) Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string

Comment: Okay all are valid answers!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `str_replace` function

```
$name="a l e x" ;
$abcd = str_replace (" ", "", $name);
$res=mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM `name` WHERE `name` LIKE '%$abcd%'") or die(mysql_error());
while($x=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    echo $x['name']."<br>";
}
```

`str_replace (" ", "", $name)` helps to your problem

or by using sql

```
"SELECT *  FROM `name` WHERE `name` LIKE '%".str_replace (" ", "", $name)."%'"
```

and it removes all your white spaces.